# KnockoutJS foreach blocks main thread

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

When I have a large dataset in my viewModel and I use `foreach` to loop over an Array of Objects to render each Object as a row within a table, KnockoutJS will block the main thread until it can render, which sometimes takes minutes (!).

Here is a jsFiddle example using a dataset containing 2000 Objects, containing a `url` and a `code`. Real data will have longer URLs in some cases and 4 other columns (only 2 in this example.) I also added some simple styles because adding styles also seems to slow things down a bit during the process.

> Warning: your browser *might* break

http://jsfiddle.net/DESC3/7/

Comment: This will illustrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/DESC3/10/ It has reduced data amount since it's not needed to make the point.

Comment: Here is how the same html (2000 rows ) is rendered instantly with a different approach http://jsfiddle.net/DESC3/11/. I am not saying to do this but it just shows knockout is not very optimized...

Comment: @Esailija - Your first example is actually really quick. This is only a problem for us when there are >1000 rows. There are a couple of reasons why we pull in all of the data at one, as well. So, pagination or sending the data in chunks is not really an option.

Comment: Do you think this should be submitted as a bug?

Comment: Well technically it's not a bug but perhaps they should be made aware of it. In the meanwhile you could use a template to spit out a string, and set html the same way (not literally, use `.html` instead of `[0].innerHTML`) I did in the second example.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that if you have such large datasets you try an alternative solution. For example [slickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) renders large datasets in a much more efficient way, by only generating HTML elements for the data that is actually visible. We've used this for large datasets, and it performs well.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this. Say, you've got `viewModel.items = ko.observableArray()` that you'd like to render.

1. Have a separate non-observable array of all your data: `var itemsToRender = functionThatReturnsLargeArray()`.
2. Put some portion of your data from `itemsToRender` into your observable array. Say, 50 elements only.
3. Keep adding elements into observable array in portions inside a `setTimeout` callback.

---

*NOTE1:* You can add some time-tracking into `setTimeout` callback and increase/reduce the number of items that you add at each iteration. Your goal is to keep each callback time below 50-100 milliseconds so your application still feels responsive.

```
var batchSize = 50; // default number of items rendered per iteration
var batchOffset = 0;
function render(items, itemsToRender, done) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var startTime = new Date().getTime();
        items.pushAll(itemsToRender.slice(batchOffset, batchSize));
        batchOffset += batchSize;
        // at this point Knockout rendered next batchSize items from itemsToRender
        var endTime = new Date().getTime();
        // update batchSize for next iteration
        batchSize = batchSize * 50 / (endTime - startTime); // 50 milliseconds
        batchSize = Math.min(itemsToRender.length, batchOffset + batchSize);
        if (batchSize > 0) render() else done(); // callback if you need one
    }, 0);
}
/* I haven't actually tested the code */
```

Another batch size updating strategy could be based on target FPS. Say you'd like to achieve 60 fps update rate and thus 60 calls to `setTimeout` per 1000 milliseconds. That would take somewhat longer to process the whole collection. You can also use `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setTimeout` and see how that would work out.

**EDIT**: [Build-in throttling](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/08/31/knockout-1-3-0-beta-available/) was added into [Knockout JS 1.3](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/downloads) (currently it's in beta but seems pretty stable).

---

*NOTE2:* If some other data on the view depends on `viewModel.items` you can still map it down to original array `itemsToRender`. Say, for example, that you'd like to show the number of items in collection. If you use `viewModel.items().length` you'll end up with changing size value in the UI while more items get renderred. To avoid that you can first define your size binding as a `dependentObservable` based on `itemsToRender`, not `viewModel.items`. After you've done rendering all items you can re-map it onto `viewModel.items` if you see fit.